# Which mail server is good on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, email-server

If we have two options

- MailEnable Standard
- hMail Server

Which one we should choose?

Comment: With the complete lack of information you've provided in regards to how you intend to use the server any answer can be nothing short of guesswork. Please describe how this is to be used and the sort of mail volume you expect to see, both inbound and outbound. Also, are you only looking at those two or are you open to suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the built-in SMTP Server?

This has been asked on ServerFault: [Is the IIS SMTP Server good enough for a production server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/42544)

Answer (score 1):

I've used both, and I personally prefer hMailServer. It is extremely scriptable. That, and its out-of-the-box ability to insert HTML signatures.

Answer (score 0):

SmartermMail comes to my mind. Used it in the past, always satisfied.